# How to perform copy under async function in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, copy

Firefox version 69.

Perform both

> document.execCommand("copy")

and

> navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)

wont work within an async function. Is Firefox not allow to do so, or copy within an async function doesnt count as initiated by user interaction?

This is what i am doing:

```
    asyncFunction().then((result) => {
    try {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(JSON.stringify(result)).then(() => {
            console.log('success!')
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
    });
```

Is there a workaround about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have your async function store the results somewhere else. Add a "copy results" button that does the actual copy from that.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thank you for your reply! Adding a button is the last way to do the job in my circumstance. Is there a way to copy without user awareness?

Comment: No, as that's considered a security problem. You need direct association between a user-initiated interaction event (usually a click event; the browser sets a read-only property on these so you can't use faked events) and the clipboard copy action.

Comment: @Ouroborus Okay, at least using Chrome can avoid this problem. Thank you for your reply.